# Measurability of the set of all continuous functions

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

Consider $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ the set of all real-valued functions of real variable with the product topology. This topology induces the Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R})$. Another $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ is the cylindrical $\sigma$-algebra $\text{Cyl}(\mathbb{R})$ (or sometimes $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})^\mathbb{R}$), i.e. the coarsest $\sigma$-algebra over open cylindrical sets.

Consider $\mathcal{C}(\mathbb{R}) \subset \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ the set of all continuous functions.

1. Is $\mathcal{C}(\mathbb{R}) \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R})$?
2. Is $\mathcal{C}(\mathbb{R}) \in \text{Cyl}(\mathbb{R})$?

And why?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: hmm, why is Cyl different from $\mathcal B$? Isn't the product topology generated (by definition) by the cylindrical open sets?

Comment: As far as I know, it is not the same. The Wikipedia article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylindrical_%CF%83-algebra mentions this in the last sentence.

Comment: $\text{Cyl}(\mathbb{R})$ is the coarsest $\sigma$-algebra which contains sets $\{f\in\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R} : f(t) \in B_t, t\in I\}$, where $B_t$ is open (or Borel) set on $\mathbb{R}$ and I is a finite subset of $\mathbb{R}$. If I am not mistaken, it shouldn't be the same as $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R})$